Show that $\sup_{x \in A} \vert y(x) \vert = \sup_{x \in A} \vert \text{Re}(y(x)) \vert$ if $A$ is absolutely convex
Let $E$ be a vector space in $\mathbb{C}$. A subset $A \subseteq E$ is absolutely convex if $\lambda x + \mu y \in A \ \forall x, y \in A, \mu, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfy $\vert \lambda \vert + \vert \mu \vert \le 1$.
Let $y$ be a linear functional on $E$, and set $u = \text{Re}(y)$. Show that, if $A$ is an absolutely convex subset of $E$, we have
$$
    \sup_{x \in A} \vert y(x) \vert = \sup_{x \in A} \vert u(x) \vert
$$
Attempt. It is readily that $\vert y(x) \vert \ge \vert u(x) \vert\ \forall x$, and thus
$$
    \sup_{x \in A} \vert y(x) \vert \ge \sup_{x \in A} \vert u(x) \vert
$$
We can show that $y(x) = u(x) - i u(ix) \ \forall x \in E$. Therefore,
$$
    \vert y(x) \vert = (\vert u(x) \vert^2 + \vert u(ix) \vert^2)^{1/2}
$$
As $A$ is absolutely convex, $ix \in A \ \forall x \in E$. Therefore,
$$
    \vert u(ix) \vert \le \sup_{x \in A} \vert u(x) \vert 
$$
and thus,
$$
    \sup_{x \in A} \vert y(x) \vert \le \sqrt{2} \sup_{x \in A} \vert u(x) \vert
$$
I can't think of another way to upper bound $\sup_{x \in A} \vert y(x) \vert$, or to show $\sup_{x \in A} \vert y(x) \vert \le \sup_{x \in A} \vert u(x) \vert$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Let $x \in A$. Write $y(x)$ in polar form as $re^{i\theta}$ where $r \ge 0$ and $\theta $ is real. Let $x'=(\cos^{2} \theta -i\sin \theta \cos \theta )x$. Then $x' \in A$ (by taking $\lambda =\cos^{2} \theta -i\sin \theta \cos \theta, \mu=0$ in the hypothesis)  and $y(x')=  (\cos^{2} \theta -i\sin \theta \cos \theta) y(x)=\Re y(x)$.
